# Basic Laravel route filtering with multiple parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, closures, laravel-routing

So I'm attempting to authenticate my user's using Laravel's custom filters.  I have my LDAP PHP script working and I have essentially plugged it in to my custom filter.  However, I need to pass this script the username and password that the user enters on the log in screen; in other words, I need to pass my custom filter this username and password from the log in form.

Here is my code to help explain my problem:

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'ldapTest'), function() {
    Route::controller('apps', 'AppController', array(
        //named routes here
    ));
});
```

**filters.php**

```
Route::filter('ldapTest', function()
{
    $username = //how do I get this?
    $password = //how do I get this?

    //LDAP logic goes here; assume $ldapConn and $userDN are properly initialized
    $userBind = @ldap_bind($ldapConn, $userDN, $password);

    if($userBind)
    {
        Auth::login(//what goes here?  I want to access $username later on in applications);
        return Redirect::to('apps/home');
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Incorrect password';
    }
});
```

From reading the documentation I understand you can pass parameters as strings to filters like so: `Route::filter('ldapTest:400', function()`, but I don't understand how I could use this to pass my username and password using what I assume would be Input::get().

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `Input::get('username')` to get the value of an input field that has the name `username`. Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can pass parameters into your custom filter and in this case your filter should look like this:

```
Route::filter('ldapTest', function($route, $request, $param){
    //...
});
```

In your `Closure` the third argument will receive the parameter you passed in and it's `$param`, so you are able to pass it like this in your before filter:

```
array('before' => 'ldapTest:someString')
```

So, in the filter, the `$param` will contain `someString` but in your case that would be a bit different I think, because you want to receive the user inputs submitted through a form so to get those inputs you may use something like this in your filter's handler (Closure):

```
$username = $request->get('username'); // Assumed that username is a form field
$password = $request->get('password');
```

Also you may use `Input::get('username')` instead of `$request` if you want but it'll be working with `$request` instance variable and I would prefer that to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar needing in my project, solved with this (not so much elegant but working) workaround:

```
Route::filter('multiParamFilter', function($route, $request, $params){
     list($p1, $p2) = explode(':', $params);
     //Now you have $p1 and $p2 initialized with parameters
     ....
}
```

In routes.php you can call:

```
Route::get('path', array('before' => 'multiParamFilter:p1:p2' ......
```

*Note: It requires that you dont use ':' (or at least another symbol) in your parameter values*

Comment: You can make it a bit shorter by using list($p1, $p2) = explode(':', $params);